# Ruby on Rails: comparing dates error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
```

the line the error occurs on

```
@object.expires_at < Date.today
```

so.. how do I compare dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to rails 2.3.8 from 2.3.4..

this fixed it

```
@object.expires_at < Date.today unless @object.expires_at.nil?
```